# How to specify optional request parameter in Yaml format of Spring Cloud Contracts?

Tags: yaml, spring-cloud-contract

I have defined a contract as

```html
request:
  method: "POST"
  url: "/some/resource"
  headers:
    Content-Type: "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
  body:
    id: "id123"
    desc: "Some description"
  matchers:
    body:
    - path: "$.id"
      type: "by_regex"
      predefined: "non_blank"
response:
  status: 200
  headers:
    Content-Type: "application/json"
  body:    
    message: "Success"
```

I want to make `desc` field optional.
In groovy dsl syntax I can define as  `desc: optional(regex(nonBlank()))`
What is the Yaml equivalent for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't make a field optional. You can make a value of the given key optional. So what that groovy code does is that it wraps the regex in a 0 or 1 occurrence value. You can write such an expression yourself in yaml

Comment: Thanks, can you show how the value for `desc` in the above can be made optional? or point to a documentation?
I am reading https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-contract/reference/html/project-features.html#yaml
Closest thing I found was minOccurence but that is not working for me.

Comment: You can write a regex and wrap it in (...)? Which means 0 or 1 occurrence

Comment: Thanks, the problem was solved  by using - 
```
    - path: "$.desc"
      type: "by_regex"
      value: "(^\\s*\\S[\\S\\s]*)?"
```